# Android : Reading XML data from URL using JAVA

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, augmented-reality

Hi iam trying to read the XML data from URL

XML Structure is follows :

```
<specialoffers>
  <categories>...</categories>
  <categories>...</categories>
  <categories>...</categories>
  <categories>...</categories>
  <categories>...</categories>
  <categories>...</categories>
```

XML :

```
<specialoffers>
<categories>
   <category>
       <![CDATA[ 0% Installment Payment Plan Offers ]]>
   </category>
   <merchants>
       <merchantname>
         <![CDATA[ EmaxIPP ]]>
       </merchantname>
       <merchantbigimage>
         <![CDATA[
         http://www.XXX.com/Images/Emax%20New%20-%20190x73-1_tcm20-48180.jpg]]>
         </merchantbigimage>

        <merchantsmallimage>
         <![CDATA[
         http://www.XXX.com/Images/Emax%20New%20-%20104x75-1_tcm20-48179.jpg
          ]]>
         </merchantsmallimage>

        <merchantmobileimage>
         <![CDATA[ http://www.XXX.com ]]>
       </merchantmobileimage>
       <mobilehighlight>
         <![CDATA[
        Enjoy 0% Installment Payment Plan for 3 months on 
        all purchases made </b>
        ]]>
       </mobilehighlight>
        <locations>
             <location>
                <emirate>
               <![CDATA[ XXX]]>
                </emirate>
               <address>
               <![CDATA[ Center 1 ]]>
               </address>
               <latitude>
               <![CDATA[ 51.169601 ]]>
                  </latitude>
               <longitude>
               <![CDATA[ 61.240395 ]]>
               </longitude>
             </location>
       </merchants>

   </categories>
 </specialoffers>
```

And the Java code is as follows :

```
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(url.openStream());

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("category");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println(element.getFirstChild().getTextContent());



        NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("merchants");
        Element getChds = (Element)nodeList2.item(i);

        for (int  j=0; j < nodeList.getLength() ; j++){

            NodeList nodeList3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("merchantname");
            Element element1 = (Element)nodeList3.item(j);
            System.out.println("--"+element1.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

Iam trying to display Category and Merchant Name in all " Categories " and Iam able to display Category name of all categories but failing to merchant names.

Here is the Actual xml string : http://www.adcb.com/specialoffers-test.xml

Tring to print :

```
0% Installment Payment Plan Offers 
 --EmaxIPP 
 --Delma Medical Centre
 .
 .
Dining Offers
 --Lounge Cafe
 --India Palace Restaurant
 .
 .
```

Comment: What's wrong? It seems to be printing correctly for me.

Comment: Iam getting same merchant names for every Category list. Please find my expected output

Answer (score 2):

When trying to print the `merchants`, you are actually iterating over the length of the `category` `NodeList` called `nodeList`. You need to iterate over `nodeList2`.

```
for (int  j=0; j < nodeList2.getLength() ; j++){ 
    NodeList nodeList3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("merchantname");
    Element element1 = (Element)nodeList3.item(j);
    System.out.println("--"+element1.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
}
```

You were using the length of `nodeList` which is 6, instead of the length of `nodeList2` which is 16. Using the above will print

```
--EmaxIPP
--Delma Medical Centre
--Lounge Cafe
--India Palace Restaurant
--Ashas-Wafi
--Dome Cafe
--Delma Medical Center
--Jacky's Electronics
--Dreamland Aqua Park
--Yas Island Rotana
--Dubai Dolpharium
--Autodrome
--Singapore - Grand Hyatt Singapore
--Thailand - Dusit Thani Laguna Phuket
--Joyalukkas
--LifeStyle Fine Jewelry
```

Comment: But this output is not matching with what iam expecting, i want to list like " Category  and their corresponding merchants "

Comment: @user2761566 Based on the XML, what you want to do is to originally get the `<categories>` elements, not the `<category>`. From each `<categories>` Node you can get a `<category>` node with the name and a number of `<merchants>` nodes.